# SQl Database back up showing error "Exception of type "System.OutofMemoryException" was thrown.(mscorlib)"

Tags: mysql, database, exception, out-of-memory, database-backups

I need to take a backup of a SQL database with data. I select

*Tasks -> Generate Scripts... -> Next -> Next and in Table view option I changed Script Data FALSE to TRUE -> Next -> Select all -> Script to New Query Window -> Finish*.

But it end up with an error:

**"Exception of type "System.OutofMemoryException" was thrown.(mscorlib)"**.

I have checked the memory space of my drives. C drive is having more than 10 GB and D drive is having more than 3 GB but the database is only 500MB. That error is showing for 1 particular table "TBL_SUMM_MENUOPTION" which is an empty table. May I know how to fix this issue? How to take that database backup with out this error?

Screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Note that the error clearly indicates out of **memory**, not disk space. You should check RAM amounts on both client and server (don't remember on which one is the process executed) and look if the server is taking too much memory or if other programs are taking it all for themselves.

Comment: BTW, if you want to have a backup, why don't simply create a *backup*? (Tasks -> Backup ->Database). That's much preferable to simply generating tons of scripts with the data.

Comment: If I create backup using _Tasks -> Backup -> Database_ will create database with data? or simply it will create tables and SP with only field names?

Comment: Of course a full backup will copy **everything**, including table structure, views, triggers, stored procedures and most important all data with its indexes and current statistics. That's the correct way to make a backup copy, instead of the unreliable "generate scripts" which is intended for other purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Alejandro stated in his comment, Instead of taking backup using *Tasks -> Generate Scripts... -> Next -> Next and in Table view option I changed Script Data FALSE to TRUE -> Next -> Select all -> Script to New Query Window -> Finish*. I took backup by using *Tasks -> Backup ->Database* which is very simple.